# Is credit card transaction expected to be declined for test transaction?

Tags: api, paypal, transactions

I am doing some development using payflow api 
I created test only payflow account. (Transaction Process Mode = Test)

My program uses secure token with hosted check out page.

When I submit my credit card info in the hosted checkout page, the error URL of my program gets called with error code "12" transaction declined.

I try manual testing the payment by going to Paypal Manager-->Virtual Terminal-->Single Transaction. I filled up all the info (along with actual credit card details) and I got the same error - Result Code = 12.  Response Message = Declined.
But when I click on "Transaction Details" --> Response Message (Declined) "Click here for fraud details";   it says "Status" as "Passed".

I tried this for both transaction type Sale and Authorize.

So is the error code 12 and Response message "Declined" is because of "Transaction Mode" is Test?

some extra info:
    TYPE = 'S'
    PREFPSMSG = 'No Rules Triggered'
    RESPMSG = 'Declined'
    RESULT = '12'

Comment: Can you post the response from the PayPal for any decline transaction ?

Comment: @Ehsan cont... %2015:26:24&NAMETOSHIP=Mark+Farrel&ZIP=99999&BILLTOCOUNTRY=US&EXPDATE=0616&STATETOSHIP=CA&RESPMSG=Declined&COUNTRY=US&BILLTOZIP=99999&SHIPTOSTREET=272+Morgana+Way&SHIPTOSTATE=CA&BILLTOCITY=Havana&TAX=0.00&BILLTOSTATE=CA&CARDTYPE=0&FIRSTNAME=Mark&AVSDATA=XXN&CITYTOSHIP=Havana&SECURETOKEN=ewwefwefwfewfkK29MBUkEXJxACT&PREFPSMSG=No%20Rules%20Triggered&SECURETOKENID=23783123453&CITY=Havana&NAME=Mark+Farrel&HOSTCODE=D&BILLTOSTREET=272+Morgana+Way&COUNTRYTOSHIP=US&RESULT=12&TRXTYPE=S&ADDRESS=272+Morgana+Way

Comment: @Eshan This is the sile post error URL parameter sent by the hosted checkout page (certain values like address,etc..have been changed to protect privacy. Original values are actual values used for actual credit card payment): TYPE=S&STATE=CA&ACCT=1234&ZIPTOSHIP=99999&BILLTOLASTNAME=Mark&BILLTONAME=Mark%20‌​Farrel&SHIPTOCITY=Havana&LASTNAME=Farrel&PNREF=A7wfe342A468614&TENDER=CC&METHOD=CC&S‌​HIPTOZIP=99999&ADDRESSTOSHIP=272+Morgana+Way&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=Mark&AMT=45.00&SHIPT‌​OCOUNTRY=US&TRANSTIME=2014-11-04%2015:26:24

Comment: Did you try to the test credit card 4111111111111111 with any future expdate and cvv as 123?

Comment: @Ehsan  No I didn't before. I just did just now.  And the transaction was approved/successful. RESULT=0,RESPMSG=Approved,PREFPSMSG=No Rules Triggered.  However my silent post URL was not called, but the url for "Return URL when Silent Post fails" was called instead with the details of the transaction (the transaction was voided).    If I uncheck the "Void transaction when..", I will be directed to a paypal page saying transaction of successful (and not voided).   The silent post URL just accepts arbitrary URL parameters and displays a simple message. Do you know why would my silent post fail ?

Answer (score 1):

Payflow and Braintree (I believe) give you [different results](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/#testing-transactions) based on what amount so that you can test decline, etc. Make sure your test amount is less than $1001.

Comment: This is correct. When in test mode, you can trigger paypal result code responses based on your dollar amount over $1000 (for example, to test getting back a result code of 12, you attempt a test charge using dollar amount $1012).